# Radius of convergence of $\sqrt{1+\sin(2x)}$

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{1+\sin(2x)}$. The nearest points of singularities are at $x=-\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $x=\frac{3\pi}{4}$. Thus, the radius of convergence $R$ has to be at most $\frac{\pi}{4}$, which in turn means the interval of convergence is at most $(-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4})$ However when I sketched the Maclaurin series of f using Geogebra up to degree 9, [image] the convergence is from $(-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{4})$.

I am a bit confused because this is beyond my understanding of power series and radius of convergence. Would appreciate any form of help to enlighten me about this.

Comment: It's because the singularities aren't poles but rather cusps. Radii of convergence are not capable of detecting cusps like they are with poles.

Comment: Maclaurin series actually has an infinite radius of convergence. On $[-\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{3\pi}{4}]$ the function (together with all its derivatives) coincides with the function $\sin x+\cos x$, so by trying to find the Maclaurin series of the original function, you have in fact found the Maclaurin series of $\sin x+\cos x$, which has infinite radius of convergence. What you have here is - outside of $[-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{4}]$ the Maclaurin series does not converge to _your_ function but to $\sin x+\cos x$.

Comment: A simpler case: $f(x)=|x-1|=\begin{cases}x-1&x\ge 1\\1-x&x\le 1\end{cases}$. Its Maclaurin series is $1-x$, is finite, and obviously has the infinite radius of convergence (for all meaningful interpretations of "radius of convergence"), but it actually represents $g(x)=1-x$ and not $f(x)$ on $[1,\infty)$. Now whether this will prompt some math educator to tweak the definitions and say that in this case we would "assume" the "radius of convergence" to "be" $1$ (or whatever) - I doubt it, hope it is not like that in your books.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{1+\sin (2x)}$$
$$=\sqrt{\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x) + 2 \sin(x) \cos(x)} $$
$$=\sqrt{(\cos(x) + \sin(x))^2}$$
$$=|\cos(x) + \sin(x)|$$

I believe this gives you a good start :-)

Comment: Ah yes, I figured this out when I read Bishop's reply. Thank you!